Add flow rules on ODL calcium release
I'm very new to sdn and virtualization world 
I'm following this openflowplugin documentation (well there's no explanation for openflowplugin in under calcium release, that's why I'm reading potasium's) 
however these:

localhost:8181/rests/data/network-topology:network-topology/topology=flow%3A1?content=nonconfig
localhost:8181/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow%3A1?content=nonconfig
localhost:8181/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow%3A1/node-connector=openflow%3A1%3A2?content=nonconfig

are working fine
but this one:

localhost:8181/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow%3A1/table=0?content=nonconfig

from that : part
is not working, if I try to access it via browser directly it says: Hmmm… can't reach this page
or via GET request:
{
    "errors": {
        "error": [
            {
                "error-tag": "data-missing",
                "error-message": "Schema for '(urn:opendaylight:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)table' not found",
                "error-type": "protocol"
            }
        ]
    }
}

which provoke me from adding flows on:

localhost:8181/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow%3A1/table=0/flow=1

P.S : My topology has 6 OVS and 2 hosts created via mininet and connected to the controller on localhost:6653, I can't ping yet because there's no flow rules yet but getallnodes on karaf shell shows me all the 6 nodes (switches) which means they're connected right?
